# Should I encode after json.dumps(...)?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding

As I learnt, I now *always decode* user input coming to my script (a Python web server).
And I always encode output, for example when I send data to the client from the server, in a websocket connection.

Should I do:

```
ws.send(json.dumps({'message' : message, 'id': i}))
```

or

```
ws.send(json.dumps({'message' : message, 'id': i}).encode('utf8'))
```

?

The first seems ok in Python 2.7, because it seems that the result of `json.dumps(...)` is already encoded:

```
print type(json.dumps({'message' : message, 'id': i}))
# <type 'str'>
```

## Question:

**Should we `.encode('utf8')` or not after a `json.dumps()` ?**

Answer (score 1):

In general, Data you send and receive via a socket connection is a handshake between client and server. Client should send the data acceptable by server, it doesn't matter whether it is `utf-8` or `latin`.

In short, do whatever encoding you like but take in mind that your server expects the same.

Regarding your question:

> Should we .encode('utf8') or not after a json.dumps() ?

Here is an example:

```
>>> a = {'a': 'Hello'}
>>> str_a = json.dumps(a)    # type(str_a) --> <class 'str'>
>>> bytes_a = json.dumps(a).encode('utf8')   # type(bytes_a)  --> <class 'bytes'>
```

Lets check the memory size of both:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(str_a)
63
>>> sys.getsizeof(bytes_a)
47
```

Cleary bytes string consume less memory than normal string. It is better choice to send the encoded data for less network usage. For data transfer through socket, it is a major factor to be considered.